# htaccess that's redirect a folder that's no longer exists

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect entire folder that's no longer exists to the homepage.

I try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_thats_no_longer_exists/$ /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_thats_no_longer_exists /
RedirectMatch 301 /folder_thats_no_longer_exists /
```

But this solutions don't work :

In fact, after this tries, the URL is still : http://www.example.com/folder_thats_no_longer_exists/page.htm but with content of the homepage (that's cause display errors).

I just want :
http://www.example.com/folder_thats_no_longer_exists/page.htm that goes to http://www.example.com/ with 301 redirect.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule at top of your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder_thats_no_longer_exists(/.*)?$ /
```

Remember to clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.